# Swagger UI requestInterceptor throws the "Cannot set property 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of undefined" error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and Swagger to create API documentation.

composer require:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "darkaonline/l5-swagger": "^5.7.3",
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
    "laravel/passport": "~4.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground": "^2.1",
    "nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.15",
    "paragonie/random_compat": "~2.0",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "3.*"
},
```

Everything is working OK, but when I try to execute a request in Swagger UI, I get an error:

```
actions.js:453
TypeError: Cannot set property 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' of undefined
```

This is the code that throws the error:

```
 requestInterceptor: function() {
      this.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 'hM4lUy0ednXXWEFwYc1iRprnSuBuPwQH6Z4pi6v8';
      return this;
    },
```

Why does the error occur?

Comment: Did you manager to fix this error ? Did you need to change Swagger files in your Laravel app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your [`requestInterceptor`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#user-content-requestinterceptor) function is missing an argument.

The `requestInterceptor` function must have one argument, say, `req`. This argument provides access to the request data. The function must return the modified request.

```
requestInterceptor: function(req) {
  req.headers['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = 'hM4lUy0ednXXWEFwYc1iRprnSuBuPwQH6Z4pi6v8';
  return req;
},
```